# Divs won't position correctly

Tags: html, css

Im trying to display my web app using divs however it doesnt seem to display properly. I want the *title, picture the left description on the right of the picture*, I've managed to get this correct.

However then I want my *portion number, preparation time, utensils, ingredients and finally method in that order to just flow in that order*. However it's not working, I've created a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9DDw/1)  would be great if you could update it and help.

```
<div id="description">
    <p class="textDes">
        <label for="descrip">Enter a recipe Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="descrip" >
    </p>
</div>
```

Like this picture [image: DIV]

Comment: Here is the tidier version of that JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e9DDw/1/ I would suggest putting this one in your description above.

Comment: @Nick Can you draw something and show what you wanna achieve?

Comment: I just want my utensil div to be under the preperation one, then the ingredient div under utensil and then method under ingredient

Comment: @PraveenKumar great idea yes please give us a rough sketch.  This is very jumbled and useless as a representation of what you want.  Also you need to include the javascript code that we don't have access to (`js/app.js` and `js/jquery.elastic.source.js`)

Comment: The OP is primarily wanting the presentation, so just the image can help us in understanding what OP needs and correct it if possible. What say @NickPocock?

Comment: What do you want to do? please tell me your actual requirement !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clear: left` to `#portionPrep` and don't float the divs inside it

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9DDw/8/)

Comment: That works great, could you quickly explain the clear:left? Thanks

Comment: the `clear`  property clears floating element in it's direction, it's the same as having this div take 100% of the width.